# Add the "can no longer be reproduced" and "does not seek input and discussion" close reasons to all meta sites

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons, off-topic, per-site-meta

Meta Stack Exchange and Meta Stack Overflow have two very useful off-topic close reasons in the closing dialog. I'm talking specifically about these two:

> This question **does not appear to seek input and discussion** from the community. If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites, please describe it in detail. See also: [What is "meta"? How does it work?](/help/whats-meta)

and

> The problem described here **can no longer be reproduced**. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.

These are highly useful close reasons and I see them used a lot on MSO and MSE. However, I've noticed one problem: **they only exist on two sites**. I frequently find questions that don't seek input and discussion from the community or that can no longer be reproduced on plenty of other meta sites.

For example, just yesterday I found [a bug report](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/mathjax-error-for-newcommand-defined-xrightarrow-%E2%86%92) on Operations Research Meta that can no longer be reproduced. Because the standard "can no longer be reproduced" close reason doesn't exist on OR.Meta, we had to use a custom close reason (which doesn't actually show up in the dialog when the question is closed).

[image]

My request is to add these two close reasons to all per-site metas in the <strike>universe</strike> Stack Exchange network so the OP can get a more specific reason on why their question was closed, and so nobody has to resort to custom close reasons nearly as much.

Comment: This could become hard to backfill for all metas but I think it is reasonable for new(er) sites.

Comment: This was probably asked before, because I remember the advice being, at least for no longer repo’d,  to write an answer. That requires only two people to take the question out of the unanswered list while closing requires five.